Looking for title/author of short story about a single mother whose employer-provided smart home turns out to be controlled by a coworker/friend
I'm pretty sure I came across this story during school (was an English major), but can't remember in what class or who the author was. I remember that the main character was a single mother who, at the start of the story, was looking for a job that would allow her to better balance work and motherhood. She lands a job with a company that provides her with a state-of-the-art smart home and free (or very cheap?) day care services. The home is able to care for the child's general needs if she has to work late and she can monitor (and speak to?) her child through cameras in the home.
After some time passes, strange things start happening in the home. She asks her employer to look into it and fix the AI, but they always say that they can't see anything wrong in the code. Eventually, the smart home starts putting her child in danger and it comes out that the guy she had become very close with in the tech department had been causing the issues with the AI and covering his tracks. I think he did it because of some obsession with her which made him want to get close to her/have a relationship with her.
Any help is greatly appreciated as I remember the story very clearly but cannot seem to remember (or find) what it was called to read it again

In roughly which year did you read this?
